# Itzykson and Zuber: Reduced $T$-matrix

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, conservation-laws, dirac-delta-distributions, s-matrix-theory

Could someone help me understand the reduced $T$-matrix mentioned in Itzykson and Zuber, eq.

$$\langle{f}| T|p_1p_2\rangle=(2\pi)^4\delta^4(P_f-p_1-p_2)\langle f|\mathcal{T}|p_1p_2\rangle. \tag{5-7}$$

How is it possible to extract the delta function?

Answer (score 2):

One way to say it is that total 4-momentum conservation
$$ (P_f^{\mu}-p_1^{\mu}-p_2^{\mu})\langle{f}| T|p_1p_2\rangle~=~0, \qquad \mu~\in~\{0,1,2,3\}, $$
implies that the $T$-matrix element 
$$\langle{f}| T|p_1p_2\rangle\quad\propto\quad\delta^4(P_f-p_1-p_2)$$
is proportional to a 4D [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Ok, that makes sense. It doesnt explain the $2\pi$-terms however. Do you know how come this matrix is used when calculating scattering? As opposed to the off-shell one.

Comment: Think of $(2\pi)^4$ as a normalization convention.